# Traceback error while executing my arp_spoofing python script

Tags: python, arp, spoofing

#### This is a part of my code. The problem is around the def get_mac(ip) class

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy
import time
import sys
```

#### This is where the spoof(ip) variable is created

```
def get_mac(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_request
    answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]

    return answered_list[0][1].hwsrc
```

#### This is where we spoof the target

```
def spoof(target_ip, spoof_ip):
    packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=target_ip, hwdst=target_mac, psrc=spoof_ip)
    target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)
    scapy.send(packet, verbose=False)

def restore(destination_ip, source_ip):
[...]

target_ip = "..."
gateway_ip = "..."
sent_packet_count = 0
```

#### The code can't reach this part

```
try:
    spoof("target_ip", "gateway_ip")
    spoof("gateway_ip", "target_ip")
    sent_packet_count = sent_packet_count + 2
    print("\r[+] Packets sent: " + str(sent_packet_count)),
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Can you provide more details.  What are you trying to do?  What does the stackTrace say?  In waht context is this spoof function called?

Comment: Actually, this is an alt account for a semester homework, but mostly, this is the code from an Udemy course : https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-python-and-ethical-hacking-from-scratch given by Zaid. Here's the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./arp_spoofer.py", line 39
[...], line 18 in spoof target_ip = get_mac(target_ip)

and the best part:
tmp[0]=socket.gethostbyname(tmp[0]) socket.gaierror: [errno -2] Name or service not known

PyCharm on Kali is busted hahaha

@KlausD.

Comment: Add all relevant information to the question itself. And don't seperate everything into tiny pieces.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but it really isn't that important. I just want to create proof for an investigation project for my college assignments soooo ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

You're a good lad tho :) @KlausD.

Comment: If it is of no importance you are free to delete your question. On the other hand if want to receive a helpful answer please edit your question as described above.

Comment: Also, i have no clue how markdown works here when i'm using code for example. I know Google got my back, but it ain't very helpful in term of quick search. Any tips would be great (for the REAL guy behind the screen). /n Thanks